# What causes a spacecraft entering the atmosphere to catch fire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, aerodynamics, viscosity

> What causes a spacecraft entering the atmosphere to catch fire?
>
> A) surface tension of air
>
> B) viscosity of air
>
> C) high temperature of upper atmosphere
>
> D) greater proportion of oxygen in upper atmosphere

Which one is correct? Please provide me the reason.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site; we deal with conceptual and experimental problems (this is neither).

Comment: Stop posting questions straight off of a homework or test sheet. At least show why you couldn't finish it yourself.

Comment: I think this question could *easily* be made to fit rules of the site. Abdul, if you would please take the time to improve the formatting of the question and reformulate it so that you are asking a conceptual question and then it will no be rejected.

Comment: I am preparing for mcat . Please help me rather then critisizing .:(

Comment: Check [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodynamic_heating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is friction with the outer layers of the atmosphere and the relatively large velocities of the spacecraft which produce these amounts of heat.

Hope this is helpful

UPDATE:

For atmospheric re-entry of a space vehicle (or object) the relatively large (super-sonic) velocities are the main factor of the heating of the object (along with the constitution and density of atmospheric layers)

Wikipedia<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system#Why_TPS_is_needed)</sup>:

> Reentry heating differs from the normal atmospheric heating associated
>   with jet aircraft, and this governed TPS design and characteristics.
>   The skin of high-speed jet aircraft can also become hot, but this is
>   from frictional heating due to atmospheric friction, similar to
>   warming ones hands by rubbing them together. The orbiter reentered the
>   atmosphere as a blunt body by having a very high (40-degree) angle of
>   attack, with its broad lower surface facing the direction of flight.
>   Over 80% of the heating the orbiter experiences during reentry is
>   caused by compression of the air ahead of the hypersonic vehicle, in
>   accordance with the basic thermodynamic relation between pressure and
>   temperature. A hot shock wave was created in front of the vehicle,
>   which deflected most of the heat and prevented the orbiter's surface
>   from directly contacting the peak heat. Therefore reentry heating was
>   largely [convective heat transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection)..

References:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system#Why_TPS_is_needed
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection